# spring security binding to LDAP with bindDN - bindCredential

Tags: authentication, bind, spring-security-ldap

We have an ldap that is configure to bind with a bindDN different from the user logging in and its own bindCredential as well.

```
bindDN    cn=appUser,dc=testOrgManagement,dc=com
bindCredential:   somePassword
```

I am trying to configure Spring security LDAP module to use it but it seems that by default it tries to bind as the authenticated user which will not be able to read the roles so it returns no roles.

Tried the following but to no avail.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true) 
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {




    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldaps://ldap.dev.testorg.com:636/")
                    .managerDn("cn=appUser,dc=testOrgManagement,dc=com")
                    .managerPassword("somePassword")
                    .and()
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .userSearchBase("ou=division1,dc=testorg,dc=com")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=division1,dc=testorg,dc=com")
                .groupSearchFilter("(uniqueMember={1})")
                .groupRoleAttribute("cn" )
                .authoritiesMapper(grantedAuthoritiesMapper());
    }


    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return new GrantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
            Set roles = new HashSet<LdapAuthority>();

            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
                    if (SecurityRoles.getRoleMap().containsKey(authority.getAuthority())) {
                        roles.add(new LdapAuthority((String) SecurityRoles.getRoleMap().get(authority.getAuthority())));
                    }
                }

                return roles;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

It seems that spring uses BindAuthenticator.java which tries to bind as the user and that does not return any roles when searching. I thought that managerDn and managerPassword were actually the bindDN and its credential but it does not seem to be the case. It seems to be just a user rather.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thank you!